# How can I bind own data to the history object using JQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, history

I'm looking for a nice way to bind my own app data (like `currentQuestion`, `currentAnswer`) to the history object.

I tried to keep track in the `hashchange` event, but that gets complicated.

I try it with url parameters, but I want to have status object with some entries for each element on the history stack, so I would have to have many parameters.

Is there a way just to add an object to the history stack?

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery mobile **ajax transition** you will have access to the **same** global jquery object on all pages, you can append data to it, for example in the first page you assign currentQuestion and currentAnswer

```
$.currentQuestion = 'something';
$.currentAnswer = 'something';
```

On the next page you can access these variables easily

```
console.log($.currentQuestion);
```

That is how I move data between pages inside jquery mobile

Comment: Thanks. But I need currentQuestion and currentAnswer for every position on the stack.

Comment: yeah you can make an array $.currentQuestions = new Array(); and push data back inside

Answer (score 0):

I found the way. You can just insert variables into the history stack:

```
        var urlh = $.mobile.urlHistory;
        if( "factId" in urlh.stack[urlh.activeIndex] ) {

            // load 
            cp10.score.currentFactId = urlh.stack[urlh.activeIndex].factId;

        } else {

            // store fact id in history object
            urlh.stack[urlh.activeIndex].factId = cp10.score.currentFactId;
        }
```

Here I insert a variable 'factId'. If it is not already in the stack element (what happens when the page is first loaded), then insert it. Later (when hte user hits the back button or so) you can retrieve it from there.